# What is this cool down ban for?

Tags: discussion

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/16993/vietnhi-phuvan
Consider the  ID above I just saw that he has only one reputation while having so much of badges how is this possible ?
What is the ban for ?

Comment: I don't believe the moderators reveal that sort of information, but if you have been around long enough, and observant, you usually have a good idea why someone gets banned.

Comment: he/she was burning up and setting fire to the place, banned until next year seems excessive though. Definitely got a few badges, what on earth warrants a years suspension? Did he argue with the mods?

Answer (score 9):

Exactly as the notice says:

> This account is temporarily suspended to cool down.

The link there leads to this blog post by Jeff Atwood: https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

The reason why the user has 1 reputation despite so many posts is also clearly explained in the blog. The link is included in the notice exactly because curious users can read the blog and get more information. The fact that you are still wondering how it is possible means that you have not read the blog. Don't do that from now on, meta is not a substitute for reading the information that is already made easily available.

Also, IIRC the reasons for the cool down notice are known only to the moderators, the user, and SE employees. The moderators and SE employees will not divulge the reasons to other users, so that leaves you with the user. You are free to consider contacting him to know the exact reasons. However, I personally recommend you to avoid wasting any further time over it.